# Linear Algebra Basis, restrictions, linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 7
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How can I find a basis of the column space of this matrix?

Under what condition is the vector 
$$
u=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ b-2 \\ b\end{bmatrix}
$$
in the column space of the matrix $A$? In this case present $u$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors. P.S i really need help with the last part

Comment: What do you mean by “basis of the matrix?”

Comment: Sorry basis of the column space

Comment: How many linearly independent columns do you have.  Chose that many to form your basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as the comments suggested but a method that won't involve any guessing is the following. Row reduce and note the place of the leading ones (i.e on which column). Then the basis you are looking for is the columns with the leading one in the ORIGINAL matrix.

So in this case the basis is $\{ (1,0,2), (1,0,3) \}$

As for the second question, I will leave it to you. (Hint: one way to do this is to set up a matrix with the columns from the basis above)

Okay in light of your comment I can get you started:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & b-2\\
2 & 3 & b
\end{array}\right]
$$

See for what b does the matrix have a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the last part is the one I really need